# How to dynamically import css url in angular

Tags: css, angular

I am working on multi tenant application in angular.
For that am trying to apply css from different clients
@import url('http://myserver/themes/ABC/css/component1.css');

@import url('http://myserver/themes/DEF/css/component1.css');

I want client name to be fetched from ts file and then import corresponding css.How can I do that?Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I came across this today looking for the same thing. In the end, adding an external stylesheet is easiest done by simple DOM manipulation:

```
  addImport(url: string): void  {
    const linkElement = document.createElement('link');
    linkElement.rel = 'stylesheet';
    linkElement.href = url;
    linkElement.id = this.importedFontUrlStyleId;
    document.head.appendChild(linkElement);
  }
```

I'm setting `this.importedFontUrlStyleId` here so later I can remove the stylesheet with

```
const importedFontSheet = document.head.querySelector(`#${this.importedFontUrlStyleId}`);
if (importedFontSheet) {
  document.head.removeChild(importedFontSheet);
}
```

The security risk of importing a variable stylesheet should be obvious.